# PhantomJS - select value from page

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs

How to select value from the webpage using PhantomJS? Here is code in html:

```
<html lang="en-US" class="xxx">
  <head></head>
  <body class="xxxx">
    <section class="Section">
      <div id="mocha">
        <ul id="mocha-stats">
          <li class="passes">
            <a href="">passes:</a> 
            <em>443</em>
          </li>
          <li class="failures">
            <a href="">failures:</a> 
            <em>4</em>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to select value from the passes which is 443. Here is my code, but it returns null.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://localhost:9001/';

page.open(url, function (status) {
  if (status === 'success') {
    var input = page.evaluate(function() {
      return document.querySelectorAll("li.passes").value;
    }, 2000);
    console.log(input);
    phantom.exit();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll("li.passes")` returns a collection with the single `li` element that matches that selector. You need to change your code to
`document.querySelectorAll("li.passes > em")[0].textContent`. This will match the `em` inside the `li` and return its text content.

Answer (score 1):

The li tag doesn't have a value, it has innerText or innerHTML.  In this case, the innerHTML has two children, an anchor tag and an emphasis tag.

If you are sure that every instance of what you are fetching will be emphasized, you can query on each returned value for the em field and get the innerHTML of that to get your final value, instead of

```
console.log(input)
```

you would have

```
if (input.length === 0) {
    console.log('No passes found.');
} else {
    for (var ndx = 0; ndx < input.length; ndx++) {
    console.log(input[ndx].querySelector('em').innerText);
}
```

I kept the answer as close to your original code as i could, but I would recommend putting in some error checks, ie if input[ndx] has no em tag.  If a classes without an em field should be ignored, you can include the em descendant in your original querySelectorAll('.classes > em')

Of course, if you're originating the html yourself, you could put the tag on the em field (or wherever the value is) and eliminate a lot of hassle.